# Создать LXC (Proxmox) из Ansible

Tags: ansible, lxc, proxmox

Доброго времени суток всем!
Не могу создать LXC в Proxmox через плейбук Ansible.
Плейбук:

```
- name: Create LXC
  proxmox:
    node: PVE-03
    api_user: root@pam
    api_password: password
    api_host: 192.168.254.23
    password: 11111
    hostname: ans
    ostemplate: data:vztmpl/debian-9.0-standard_9.5-1_amd64.tar.gz
```

Выхлоп:

```
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_proxmox_payload_oiGj7T/__main__.py", line 482, in main
    proxmox = ProxmoxAPI(api_host, user=api_user, password=api_password, verify_ssl=validate_certs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/proxmoxer/core.py", line 106, in __init__
    self._backend = importlib.import_module('.backends.%s' % backend, 'proxmoxer').Backend(host, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/proxmoxer/backends/https.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.auth = ProxmoxHTTPAuth(self.base_url, user, password, verify_ssl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/proxmoxer/backends/https.py", line 46, in __init__
    raise AuthenticationError("Couldn't authenticate user: {0} to {1}".format(username, base_url + "/access/ticket"))

fatal: [192.168.254.23]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_host": "192.168.254.23", 
            "api_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "api_user": "********@pam", 
            "cores": 1, 
            "cpus": 1, 
            "cpuunits": 1000, 
            "disk": "3", 
            "force": false, 
            "hostname": "ans", 
            "ip_address": null, 
            "memory": 512, 
            "mounts": null, 
            "nameserver": null, 
            "netif": null, 
            "node": "PVE-03", 
            "onboot": false, 
            "ostemplate": "data:vztmpl/debian-9.0-standard_9.5-1_amd64.tar.gz", 
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "pool": null, 
            "pubkey": null, 
            "searchdomain": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "storage": "local", 
            "swap": 0, 
            "timeout": 30, 
            "unprivileged": false, 
            "validate_certs": false, 
            "vmid": null
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "authorization on proxmox cluster failed with exception: Couldn't authenticate user: ********@pam to https://192.168.254.23:8006/api2/json/access/ticket"
}
```

Comment: Ну у тебя там в конце говорится, что с логином\пассом\ацл не то.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt full-upgrade
```

на Proxmox спасло отца русской демократии.

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает такой вариант:

```
- name: test container
  when:
    - ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
    - ansible_distribution_release == 'stretch'
  proxmox:
    vmid: 104
    node: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    api_user: root@pam
    api_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    api_host: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    hostname: container-test-08
    ostemplate: 'iso-and-vztmpl:vztmpl/ubuntu-current.tar.xz'
    storage: local-lvm
    memory: 512
    state: "{{ item }}"
    netif: '{"net0":"name=eth0,ip=dhcp,ip6=dhcp,bridge=vmbr0"}'
  with_items:
    - present
    - started
```